# Diff sem comparar espaços ou quebra de linha

Tags: diff

ALguém conhece algum programa capaz de fazer um diff de 2 arquivos, mas que

não compare os espaços ou quebras de linha.

Ex: eu tenho um aquivo de texto que pode ter espaços ou quebras de linha.

Não me importa a formatação, tudo que preciso saber é se o texto está segundo uma ordem.

Answer (score 2):

[WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) faz isso.

Basta configurar em Editar > Opções... > Comparar

Comment: Não faz. tenho  ele instalado, ele ignora os espaços em branco, mas não as quebras.

Answer (score 2):

Experimente [wdiff](http://www.gnu.org/software/wdiff/), que faz comparação baseada em palavras.